# How to get store name in template?

Tags: magento2, template, stores

How is it possible to output the current store name in a Magento 2 custom template with a custom block?

Comment: what template??

Comment: custom template using a custom block

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you need to use the instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` in your block:

Create the method `getStoreName()`

```
public function getStoreName()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'general/store_information/name',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

and call in your template `echo $this->getStoreName()`

Comment: Loos like a great solution, but I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function dispatch() on a non-object in /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php on line 637.

Comment: clear the var/generation folder

Comment: @Marius 's approach is right, but it didn't work for me. Instead I've used  `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager`  
in constructor and  
`public function getStoreName()  
    {  
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getName();  
    }`  
Instead of `getName()` you can use `getCode()`, `getId()`.

Answer (score 11):

Use store manager, which holds information about active store. If custom block is not inherited from `Template` block, inject dependency on `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in construct.

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block;

class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Get current store name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentStoreName()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
    }
}
```

Then in template:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \VendorName\ModuleName\Block\CustomBlock
 */
echo "<h1>Current store name is '{$block->getCurrentStoreName()}'</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I don't want to show the store view name.Searched for the store name of the configuration.

Comment: It always returns 'Default Store View' instead of my store name

Answer (score 5):

To get a store configuration value like `general/store_information/name` you can use the following

```
$config = new \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface();

echo $config->getValue('general/store_information/name');
```

However, doing this from a block or helper would be cleaner. Below is a helper class that would exist in your own custom module

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * Retrieve store name
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getStoreName()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'general/store_information/name',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Which you would inject as dependency in your block class