# how do get store in magento2?

Tags: magento2, multistore, core-config-data

i have custom tempalte. I get template store view in my block.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {

        $this->getToolbar()->addChild(
            'store_switcher_xanka',
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher',
            [
                'label' => __('Store View:'),
                'template' => 'Magento_Backend::store\switcher.phtml',
                'class' => 'add primary add-design-change'
            ]
        );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

but when i try call

```
$section = $this->getRequest()->getParam('section');
 $website = $this->getRequest()->getParam('website');
 $store = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');

        echo $store; echo $website ;echo $website ;die();
```

it return nothing. so how do get it. Any help me ? thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93665/magento-2-get-store-name-in-template

Comment: it not that i want.